# Powershell delete multiple file extensions from multiple folders

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I am trying to delete .txt and .pdf files older than 7 days from multiple folders on a drive.
I am not getting any errors but it doesn't seem to be working as I check the folders in explorer and they are still there unchanged.

```
$rootFolder = 'D:\Folder1\Folder2\'
$folders = 'FolderA\FolderA1\','FolderB\','FolderC1\FodlerC1\','FolderD\FolderD2\FolderD3\'

foreach($folder in $folders){
    $fullPath = ( $rootFolder + $folder + ('*.txt*','*.pdf*'))

    Get-ChildItem –Path $fullPath -include ('*.txt', '*.pdf') -recurse |  Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-7))} | Remove-Item -recurse -verbose

}
```

Also, would putting the extensions in a variable be better?

```
$rootFolder = 'D:\Folder1\Folder2\'
$folders = 'FolderA\FolderA1\','FolderB\','FolderC1\FodlerC1\','FolderD\FolderD2\FolderD3\'
$files = '.txt','.pdf'

foreach($folder in $folders){
    $fullPath = ( $rootFolder + $folder + $files)

    Get-ChildItem –Path $fullPath -include $files -recurse |  Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-7))} | Remove-Item -recurse -verbose

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definition of `$fullpath` seems to be incorrect.
Using following construct does the trick:

```
foreach ($folder in $folders) {
   $fullpath = $rootfolder + $folder + '*'
   get-childitem -path $fullpath -Include ('*.txt','*.pdf')
}
```

See official [documentation example 4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.2).